# Tool to find text message in a PDF file

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, machine-learning, sms

Goal:
Send a PDF file and a text message. Find if the text message exists in the pdf file.

The text message is a picture in the PDF file.

Problem:

- What tool do you need to use i order to use it?
- It doesn't matter if it paid service or not.
- It doesn't matter if it open source or not.

Info:

- This technology is probably based on machine learning.
- Regular user should use it without knowledge in coding.
- You only need to send a PDF file and text message and then you retrieve answer if there is a match and what result it is.

Comment: "The text message is a picture in the pdf file" - do you mean that the text message says something like "a boat" and the tool has to search the PDF for a picture of a boat?

Comment: "The text message is a picture in the PDF file", even if it is a picture of text, it is not a text message. You would have to run it though OCR first.

Answer (score 0):

No need for machine learning, *unless the pdf file is a scanned or drawn document*.

If you install the python [pdfminer six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) library you can simply run the pdf through the tool to convert it to text and then search the text for the phrase. Note that scanned/drawn documents may contain no text or garbled text without using OCR (optical character recognition).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I forgot to update a important info. Please read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract text from a pdf with pixel grahics in it, you can:

1. extract thes PNGs/JPG with a command-line tool such as `pdfimages`:

   ```
   Pdfimages  saves  images  from  a  Portable Document Format (PDF)
   file as Portable Pixmap (PPM), Portable Bitmap (PBM), 
   Portable Network Graphics  (PNG), Tagged Image File Format (TIFF), 
   JPEG, JPEG2000, or JBIG2 files.
   ```
2. Perform Online Character Recognition (OCR) on the images

A range of tools that can do both was discussed here: [Free OCR software that makes a PDF searchable (with searchable text at the right place)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocr+gratis) (11 Answers)

Another possibility is to automatically upload the images to a cloud service that extracts text (and even identifies fonts and collects all types of other metadata) such as [Google Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/?hl=en_US) - but beware , these offerings change all the time (naming, pricing, capablities).